# Plotting live data with FusionCharts

Tags: javascript, plot, fusioncharts

I'm not really a js or web dev but I'm trying to do an online dashboard for my arduino.
Can anyone help me ploting my sensor's reading to a graph of FusionCharts?
This is my code:

```
var accessToken = "xxx"; //secret
var deviceID = "xxxx" //secret

var url_hum = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/" + deviceID + "/hum_amb";


// GETTING HUMIDITY FROM SENSOR
function callback_humedad(data, status) {
  if (status == "success") {
    hum = JSON.parse(data.result);
  }
  else {
    alert("There was a problem");
  }
}

//fusion chart
const dataSource = {
  chart: {
    caption: "Nordstorm's Customer Satisfaction Score for 2017",
    lowerlimit: "0",
    upperlimit: "100",
    showvalue: "1",
    numbersuffix: "%",
    theme: "fusion",
    showtooltip: "0"
  },
  colorrange: {
    color: [
      {
        minvalue: "0",
        maxvalue: "50",
        code: "#F2726F"
      },
      {
        minvalue: "50",
        maxvalue: "75",
        code: "#FFC533"
      },
      {
        minvalue: "75",
        maxvalue: "100",
        code: "#62B58F"
      }
    ]
  },
  dials: {
    dial: [
      {
        value: "81"
      }
    ]
  }
};

FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var myChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: "angulargauge",
    renderAt: "chart-container",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    dataFormat: "json",
    dataSource
  }).render();
});
```

I tried changing the attribute `value:"81"` to `value: hum` but didn`t work. Being reading the documentation but didn't understand how to use it to my code.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the value you are getting on the variable "hum", is the chart rendering when you are setting static value as 81? Are you getting any error from fusioncharts lib?

Comment: Hi, the variable "hum" is send as a string from my arduino to the web and then parse at the top of the code in callback_humedad. If i change the value from 81 to 65 or 99 it renders correctly. If I write "hum" in value, it stops rendering.